# Adding Azure Information Protection Label to Powershell script using Outlook 2016

Tags: azure, powershell, outlook, azure-information-protection

I'm trying to add a custom header for AIP's msip_labels to a Powershell script that I'm writing.  I've figured out how to do this with .Net.SMTP using:

```
$message.Headers.Add("msip_labels","MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Enabled=True; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_SiteId=00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Owner=user2@domain.tld; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_SetDate=$((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ")); MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Name=Internal; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Application Microsoft Azure Information Protection; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_ActionId ffffffff-5555-6666-7777-888888888888; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Extended_MSFT_Method Manual")
```

Based on research I've done this should work using Outlook 2016 in theory:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$message = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

$message.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels", "MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Enabled=True; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_SiteId=00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Owner=user2@domain.tld; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_SetDate=$((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ")); MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Name=Internal; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Application=Microsoft Azure Information Protection; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_ActionId=ffffffff-5555-6666-7777-888888888888; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Extended_MSFT_Method=Manual")

$message.To = "user1@domain.tld"
$message.Cc = "user3@domain.tld"

$message.Subject = "Report"
$message.HTMLBody = @"
<p><font face = "Calibri" size = "3">Hello World</p></font>
"@

$reportMessage.Send()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook) | Out-Null
```

I confirmed this using a MAPI viewer that this is what's used in Outlook itself with other emails I've sent using just Outlook. But, when I tried running this in my script I get this error:

```
Exception setting "SetProperty": Cannot convert the "MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Enabled=True; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_SiteId=00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444;
MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Owner=user2@domain.tld; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_SetDate=$((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ")); MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Name=Internal;
MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Application=Microsoft Azure Information Protection; MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_ActionId=ffffffff-5555-6666-7777-888888888888;
MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Extended_MSFT_Method=Manual" value of type "string" to type "Object".
At C:\emailtest.ps1:21 char:1
+ $message.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Which doesn't seem to make much sense it's suppose to be a string in the MAPI schema, so I'm not sure why it thinks it should be an object. I even tried converting those values to objects using ConvertFrom-String, but it didn't work. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Headers is not a string collection. It is more like a key-value collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the string length you pass as a value. Does it work correctly?

It seems you need to use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. It doesn't have any restrictions on the string length unlike OOM if you use the `OpenProperty` method. Also, you may consider using any third-party wrapper around that API such as Redemption.

If you use `PropertyAccessor`, you must have good knowledge of exception handling logic. Below I list some roadblocks that you may run into:

- The body and content of an attachment of an Outlook items are not accessible through `PropertyAccessor`.
- The `PropertyAccessor` ignores any seconds of the date/time value
  String properties are limited in size depending on the information store type.
- Limitation: Personal Folders files (.pst) and Exchange offline folders files (.ost) cannot be more than 4,088 bytes.
- Limitation: For direct online access to Exchange mailbox or Public Folders hierarchy, the limit is 16,372 bytes.
- Binary properties only those whose values are under 4,088 byte can be retrieved or set. (If trying to use larger values, you get an out-of-memory error).

You may find the [Don't stumble over a stone working with the PropertyAccessor and StorageItem classes in Outlook 2007](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/11/21/outlook-object-model-propertyaccessor-storageitem/) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by appending a null character at the end of the string ( "`0" ) This is required by type "PtypString", required by property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxcdata/0c77892e-288e-435a-9c49-be1c20c7afdb